# What is the best way to convert a subset of string to array variables?

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion, integer

I have a string like this;

```
abc 1/2/3 3/4/5 4/5/6 6/7/7 efg 1 2 3 4 ...
```

I want to make it into;

```
String[] abc = {1/2/3, 3/4/5, 4/5/6, 6/7/7}
int[] efg = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

where abc, efg are variables NOT hardcoded but obtained from the string. My sample code doesn't work, so I am not posting it here. Please let me know what is the most efficient way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Does this string contain text, numbers, or both?

Comment: It contains both.. but it's always variable name followed by four values that should be part of that variable array or list.

Comment: What about using a HashMap to map a string ("efg") to a List of strings ({"1", "2", "3", "4"})? That is, it would be like `Map<String, List<String>> data` - note that data is the variable and both "abc" and "efg" are entries within it, and each entry represents a sequence of strings.. this is different than the psuedo-code, which doesn't make much since because Java is statically typed (and the question does not presume a Java code-generator).

Comment: It's a messy question to ask for output which contains arrays of different types.  Would you find it acceptable to get back _only_ string arrays?

Comment: Yes sure, provided I can covert the string value to the right data type when I want to use it, for arithmetic for example.

Comment: Formulate your question unambiguously. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @user2864740 - is it possible you have an example of how to do it? I need to use those values later on for arithmetic, if they are integers for example - that's the only requirement.

Comment: Hi @Behrang - I read it again, and there is nothing ambiguous in the question. It's clear I am trying to create different data types from a string value, and that there are a list of items that need to be assigned for that variable. I even have a clear example of the input and the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working script which gets very close to your stated requirements.  It generates a map of key names, where the values of arrays of strings.  I do not map an effort to map to different *types* of arrays, which just adds complexity, and maybe is even out of scope for what you intend to do with this code.

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
String input = "abc 1/2/3 3/4/5 4/5/6 6/7/7 efg 1 2 3 4";
String[] exps = input.split("\\s+(?=[A-Za-z]+)");
for (String exp : exps) {
    String[] parts = exp.split("\\s+");
    map.put(parts[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length));
}

// iterate each name, and then print out each string in a given array
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (String val : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + val);
    }
}

abc: 1/2/3
abc: 3/4/5
abc: 4/5/6
abc: 6/7/7
efg: 1
efg: 2
efg: 3
efg: 4
```

If you wanted to make the map more generic, you might have to map string names to `Object`.  But, this doesn't feel clean to me, and I would rather just map every name to an array of the same type.

To access, for example, the second value for name `efg`, you would use:

```
map.get("efg")[1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. If later in the code, I have to use the value 2 (which is efg[1] for example), how do I reference that from the map?